# Azure function in Java, http layer generated based on openapi

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I saw https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/generate-a-new-function-app-from-an-openapi-specification/

so in VSCode v1.63.2, azure functions plugin v1.6.0

but when I go to azure extension and then "Create new project" when I select Java I dont have any option to choose template ( http trigger ) but in Java I dont see this option ..
Anyone had maybe similar issue ?

thanks

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please  [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a Java Azure Function with HTTP Trigger in VS CODE we need to [***configure as  our environment***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-java#configure-your-environment) as given here .

- Java Development Kit, version 11 or 8.
- Apache Maven, version 3.0 or above.
- Visual Studio Code on one of the supported platforms.
- The Java extension pack
- The Azure Functions extension for Visual Studio Code.

As we have already configured the same in our environment, We have created One Azure Function using java which is using HTTP trigger.
In VS CODE for java when you will follow this [**`Microsoft Documentation`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-java#create-an-azure-functions-project) you can able to Create an Azure function using java with http trigger by providing the details.

***SCREENSHOT FOR REFERENCE***:-
[image]

[image]

[image]

For more information please refer this ***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION***: [***Develop Azure Functions by using Visual Studio Code***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs-code?tabs=java)